# How to customize tab header for QTabBar with a custom witdh=max? (qt style sheet)

Tags: qt, qstylesheet

I would like a TabBar like that but I don't which parameters of TabBar that I must set? (I want to use only style sheet)

I tried this :

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {

    background-color: blue;

    min-width:2000;

    with:2000;

    height:50;

}
```

but there are no changes on the screen

[image]

This is the full solution :

```
QTabWidget QTabBar{
background-color: #136ba2;
width: 256px;
font: 10pt "Arial";
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab{
background-color: #136ba2;
height: 50px;
width: 256px;
color: #e6e6e6;
}

QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:selected{
background-color: #0f5d90;
width: 256px;
}

QTabBar::tab:last {
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 678px;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain better what it is that you want and show what you have tried?

Comment: It's ok. please read my updated comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `QTabWidget::tab-bar{}` try using `QTabWidget QTabBar{}`. To set more specific attributes, use the `::tab` selector.

For example:

```
QTabWidget QTabBar{background-color: #136ba2; min-width: 2000px;}
QTabWidget QTabBar::tab{background-color: #136ba2; height: 50px; color: #e6e6e6}
QTabWidget QTabBar::tab:selected{background-color: #0f5d90;}
```

Comment: I added the full solution on the question message but it helped me a lot. Thank you :)